# É possível utilizar duas frameworks em php?

Tags: php, framework

Irei criar um sistema de estoque e gostaria de usar uma framework para facilitar o processo.Como escolher o framework ideal para trabalhar? Isto depende do que se trata o meu negócio? Se eu quiser funcionalidades de dois ou mais frameworks é possível? Ou é necessário usar apenas uma para o meu sistema? Alguém poderia me explicar...?

Por exemplo:

- CodeIgniter
- Zend Framework
- CakePHP
- Symfony

Comment: Sua pergunta, aplicada desta forma, é baseada em opiniões. Basicamente o mesmo que você perguntar numa roda de amigos qual o melhor carro pra se rodar na cidade. Cada um vai te dizer um modelo, mas no geral, todos os veículos cumpririam o papel de te levar de um ponto a outro.

Comment: Sim mas a grande questão é: Posso utilizar dois framworks para construir meu sistema???

Comment: Parece que o pessoal não lê o contexto da pergunta!

Comment: Você pode usar dois carros pra ir da sua casa pro trabalho? Em ambos os casos, sim. Mas isso é mesmo vantajoso? Ou será que vai dificultar mais que ajudar?

Comment: @RogersCorrêa então o melhor é remover o trecho "Qual framework escolher ou" do título da pergunta e manter o foco no se é possível utilizar o framework A e B em conjunto

Comment: Estava terminando uma boa resposta para usar ou não em conjunto.. :/

Comment: E meus caros, sinceramente, há diferenças entre frameworks sim, diferenças técnicas!!!!

Comment: Eu acho sim possível responder a esta pergunta sem dar opiniões.

Comment: Vota para reabrir denovo @bfavaretto

Comment: @RogersCorrêa O link que adicionou na pergunta é pura irônia. O que o cara quer dizer, na verdade, é: Use um framework haha

Comment: Rogers. O site abaixo pode ajudar. http://www.phpframeworks.com/ Acho que isso é uma decisão pessoal que você tem que avaliar os recursos de cada frameworks e o tempo que você vai gastar com aprendizado. Outra questão muito importante é analisar se no futuro, vc não vai ficar a ver navios por falta de recursos do frameworks.

Comment: Não se resume a somente decisão pessoal não @fabricio_wm, esta é uma visão muito superficial sobre frameworks. Como você mesmo citou, possível falta de recursos na ampliação do projeto, isto são características técnicas e não de gosto pessoal.

Comment: @MarceloAymone A comunidade fechou, deixo para a comunidade decidir se reabre. O meu voto decidiria sozinho.

Comment: Oloco nem citou o Laravel vou chorar... :(

Comment: Foi mal @HarryPotter!

Comment: @RogersCorrêa tranquilo, é só pra descontrair ... gostei muito da pergunta ... parabéns

Comment: Acho que o framework ideal depende do que você prioriza como sendo ideal, que pode ser desempenho, baixo acoplamento, facilidade de manutenção, segurança de continuidade, quantidade de documentação, consumo de hardware, pouca necessidade de escrita e etc... acredito que o ideal vai depender de qual o peso de cada um desses elementos para cada individuo, mas gostei muito da pergunta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Diferenças entre frameworks não são apenas de cunho pessoal não**, basta acessar este link abaixo e ver que existem sim, diferenças técnicas entre eles, diferenças, que podem trazer mais facilidades ou não no desenvolvimento da sua aplicação.

http://www.phpframeworks.com/

**Por exemplo:**
CodeIgniter não tem suporte nativo a ajax, módulos de autenticação, programação guiada por eventos, e o CakePhp tem tudo isto, mas não tem templates nativos.

Isto são sim diferenças técnicas, que dependendo da sua equipe, ou seus conhecimentos, irão fazer diferença durante o desenvolvimento, sendo assim necessário que você realize um bom levantamento de requisitos para o seu projeto para fazer uma boa escolha.

**Em que caso é possível utilizar 2 frameworks:**

Por exemplo, você constrói uma aplicação, e quer dar outra interface para ela, como REST, você poderia utilizar um framework para gerenciar o site online da aplicação e outro para dar acesso ao REST, com regras de negócios totalmente diferentes, alguns frameworks podem sim fazer tudo, outros não.

Mas cá entre nós, qual seria o benefício disto, considerando que você vai ter que reescrever regras, validações, modelos de negócio, para usar uma única base de dados.

**Casos em que é útil e comum casar mais de um framework: Tecnologias diferentes**

Framework PHP + Abstração do banco de dados, exemplo: Doctrine.

Framework PHP + Framework frontend, exemplo: Bootstrap, foundation, 960gs, etc.

Comment: Espero ter conseguido expressar minha resposta de forma simples, que faça entender, que nem tudo é igual não, e vai depender sim, dos requisitos de negócio e facilidades que quer implementar ao seu desenvolvimento.

Comment: Foi muito bom você ressaltar que Frameworks com objetivos diferentes podem ser sim utilizados em conjunto, bem observado!

Comment: É difícil escolher um framework para começar a trabalhar e fechar a questão de primeira, acho que é desmotivador para qualquer programador iniciante com FW's, achei muito difícil fazer uma escolha, mas gostei da que fiz, se tivesse um pouco de apoio técnico, talvez teria demorado menos nesta escolha.

Answer (score 1):

Embora a maioria dos Frameworks utilizam o design pattern MVC, não necessáriamente quer dizer que são escritos da mesma forma, mas sim seguindo a mesma linha de raciocínio.

Como você mesmo citou, você quer agilizar o desenvolvimento da aplicação, para isso, você deve sim utilizar um Framework, mesmo não utilizando as dezenas de modulos, funções.. que existem nele, com certeza o tempo de desenvolvimento será reduzido, isto é, depende da sua sensibilidade ao utilizar, em outras palavras, dominar.

Acredito que não seja possível utilizar duas Frameworks (Server-side)***[1]*** ao mesmo tempo, como citei no começo do texto, são parecidas mas não escritas da mesma forma, isso poderá causar inúmeros conflitos.

Mas aqui fica minha dica ao procurar um bom framework, procure aquela que:

- Atenda os requisitos de sistema (que atenda as suas expectativas)
- Possua comunidade de desenvolvimento ativa
- Documentação (Desenvolvimento, instalação e configuração)
- Possibilidade de módulos e plugins

***[1]*** Se forem frameworks com objetivos diferentes, sim é possível, Ex.: Cake PHP (Server-side) + Bootstrap (Client-side)